# Is it better to remove MKAnnotations or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkannotation

Is it better in terms of memory management, battery life and processor usage to remove currently not visible MKAnnotations from MKMapView or not?

I'm talking about BIG amounts of annotations (say ~1000) with only about 20 visible in current region at any given time. Should I let MapKit do his job with hiding of pins or should I handle adding/removing of annotations depending on visible region myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotations that are offscreen will not cause a large memory usage. `MKAnnotation` is designed to be very lightweight and you should try to keep them small. The memory hog is the associated view (the `MKAnnotationView`). If you have more than a few hundred visible it will cause a slowdown and large memory use with a possible crash on older devices. 1000 will slow down any device but probably won't crash it.

To sum up, the offscreen annotations don't matter. The problems arise when you have too many onscreen. For that you have to remove annotations to get better performance. How you decide to remove and replace annotations is a much more difficult question.

Comment: Thank you, nevan!

Talking about removing and replacing annotations - I'm working on clustering procedure and that's why I asked this question... What should I do with offscreen grouped markers? Now I think that will be fine just to ungroup them without removing :)

Comment: If the grouping isn't taking too long, I'd just group them all (even the offscreen ones). That way you don't have to deal with how to treat groups cut off by the screen edges. It also means you don't have to make more groups when the map is moved.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure to show not more than 100 annotations simultaneously. When you let MKMapView handle it, how do you prevent the user from zooming out to the whole world causing mapView to display all your 1000 annotations?

Comment: That's the problem I'm working on actually, trying to group annotations on a zoom out like in native Photos application :)
Actually, I can group and ungroup them with pretty animation already, but I'm thinking about what to do with offscreen grouped annotations...

Comment: @WASD42: Interesting. Just curious: What grouping algorithm are you using?